# Construct a matrix from a number sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the following problem that I cannot figure out how to approach, how would you do it? 

Consider the number sequence given by 

$x_0 = 0$ 
$x_1 = 1$ 
$x_{n+2} = 3x_{n+1}-2x_n$ 

Construct a matrix $A$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{n+2} \\
    x_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix}
= A
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{n+1} \\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange !! Can you please show us what you have tried ??

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- Input and Output of $A$ both have $2$ coordinates, so $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.
- $x_{n+2}=\color{red}3x_{n+1}\color{red}{-2}x_n$
- $x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}+\color{red}{0}x_n$

Answer (score 2):

If we write down $A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ 
in this general form, we have by definition of the product of matrices the following identity:

$$A
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{n+1} \\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    ax_{n+1}+bx_{n} \\
    cx_{n+1}+dx_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Do you then see how to choose the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ so that $A$ is the solution of your problem?